# Custom image size when sharing website content on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a website that has a section with shareable images with quotes. (think of all those inspirational quotes with a background image that people share on facebook)

**My approach:**

- I created individual pages for each quote with proper OG meta tags.
- I created a sharer link for each image.

**The problem**

Everything works fine, except for the size of the image. Apparently, this way of sharing content allows only 2 sizes of image. Even when I'm using og:image:width and og:image:height tags, the image never displays in it's full size.

As you can see [in this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrr7bz4pp0xyqw1/Screenshot%202015-12-29%2013.40.26.png?dl=0) the image is cropped.

I tried using custom open graph stories, but it also allows just one layout with a very small image to the left (the map layout doesn't work for me either).

The format I'd like is more like what you see when you share a photo. A full image, around 600px x 600px and the link to the website underneath it.

Do you know any way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The format that you have described may not be possible. From the docs:

> Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to
>   display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

There is a good doc on best practices [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) that you might find handy. Look for *Optimize images to generate great previews* .

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this was the answer